# WiFi problems on Lenovo Yoga 13, works for a short time and disconnects

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, lenovo, wifi-direct

I'm running a dual boot of Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10 on a Lenovo Yoga 13.

The problem is as follows: When using Ubuntu, WiFi works for a very short period of time and later disconnects. I'm only able to view one web page.

Does anyone know of ways of resolving this? Keep in mind that the PC does not have an ethernet jack.

Comment: Please edit the post to include the info from terminal for this command `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; iwconfig`